# WHERE id updating and back again into WHERE id

Tags: php

view2.php is an extension or displaying the rest of my code in another file from the other file im targeting the certain id then update it from view2.php into update_info.php but ill get this error

Notice: Undefined variable: id in . . . .

but in my database it was updated just didnt display into my webpage to shorten it

from view2.php into update_info.php back to view2.php after update but ill get this error

**Notice: Undefined variable: id in . . . .**

view2.php

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

update_info.php

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM info";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

"SOME CODES HERE"

Header("Location: view2.php?=".$row['id']);
```

Comment: You should use the function include_once instead of include in view2.php

Comment: @C.Liddell i already tried that one sir

Comment: I wasn't stating that as an answer to your question. However it's best practice to use include_once instead of include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set id parameter in your redirection part:

```
Header("Location: view2.php?id=".$row['id']);
```

instead of:

```
Header("Location: view2.php?=".$row['id']);
```

Comment: but the other targeted id was only targeting the first id in the list

Comment: This is because you are just getting the first id. When you run ```$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);``` it will return a row (first row) of your records. if you want to get all rows you need to do this in a loop like this:

    ```while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['id'];
    }```
And if you want to get an specific record in your database you need to put conditions in your SQL command.

Comment: my first view where view2 targeting the id is in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns an array so your id is probably undefined because row is an array. You should try row[0]['id'] if you want the first element and probably do some check to see if the result is not an empty variable from the db. Try var_dump(row) to see what you get from the database. Also you should use require_once for your dbconfig instead of include.

Comment: in a page view2.php and update_info.php ill get this vote view2.php?=63 same target id but view2.php didnt post the new updated data until i refresh it

Comment: @Ali Farhoudi noticed it well, you're missing the parameter in your header when you redirect: view2.php?id=$row['id']

Comment: i tried to change this $sql = "SELECT id FROM info";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); to this $time_id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id FROM info WHERE id='$time_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); but will give me a view2.php?id=